# MySQL Join based on date range

Tags: mysql

I am creating a mock e-commerce database for testing a script; I want to run the following code, but also inclued a further statement to select the cards based on expiry date.

```
SELECT customerCard.cardNumber, customer.firstName, customer.eMailAddress, customer.lastName, cardType, expiryDate
FROM customerCard
LEFT JOIN customer
USING ( eMailAddress ) 
LEFT JOIN card
USING ( cardNumber )
WHERE card.Expiry =< DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%Y')
ORDER BY  `customerCard`.`cardNumber` ASC
```

I get an error on the line with the WHERE statement - how can I fix this? What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you show us your table schema please?

Comment: Can you run it using `ON`, so we can narrow down where you are getting the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with your date format. MySQL expects dates to be in the form YYYY-MM-DD, not MM-YYYY. Also, if you're doing a left join, you probably don't want to have columns in that table in the WHERE clause, since that will filter out all the null rows that the left join is supposed to include (unless you didn't really want a left join).

Comment: you need full date ...
Where db-date between a-date and b-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the correct MySQL query statement from your help above.

```
SELECT customerCard.cardNumber, customer.firstName, customer.eMailAddress, customer.lastName, cardType, expiryDate
FROM customerCard
LEFT JOIN customer
USING ( eMailAddress ) 
LEFT JOIN card
USING ( cardNumber ) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( card.expiryDate,  '%y-%m-%d' ) <= DATE_FORMAT( 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,  '%y-%m-%d' ) 
ORDER BY  `customerCard`.`cardNumber` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following: Since no table schema/sample data provided, the code is mainly based on assumptions. such as your Expiry date is like `'mm-yyyy' format`

```
SELECT customerCard.cardNumber, customer.firstName, 
customer.eMailAddress, customer.lastName, cardType, expiryDate
FROM customerCard CC
LEFT JOIN customer CO
ON CC.eMailAddress = CO.eMailAddress 
LEFT JOIN card CD
ON CO.cardNumber = CD.cardNumber
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CD.Expiry,'%m-%Y') =< DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%Y') -- put both in same format
ORDER BY  CC.cardNumber ASC
```

Comment: When in doubt, it's always good to expand your syntax and take each joins separately(broken down in smaller pieces) to see if the data is returned.